# I am getting error while implementing ngx-Spinner 8.0.3

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I want a spinner loader to be implemented in my app.
I am following the process given here
[ https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner ]
I installed and Saved it.

And When I am importing and adding it to "imports", I am getting the following error.

Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at ngx-spinner.js:208
    at Module../node_modules/ngx-spinner/fesm5/ngx-spinner.js (ngxspinner.js:210)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:23)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)

```
npm i ngx-spinner
npm install ngx-spinner --save


aap.module.ts

    import { NgxSpinnerModule } from "ngx-spinner";

    imports: [
        // ...
        NgxSpinnerModule
    ]
```

I am not getting how to get out of this error If anyone can please help me.

Comment: What is your angular version?

Comment: And what's the version of ngx-spinner version?

Comment: Thanks @ArchitGarg.
Yes, there was a mismatch between Angular and ngx-Spinner versions.

Comment: happy to help. Consider accepting the answer if that helped.

Answer (score 5):

This must be a version mismatch between your angular version and the version of ngx-spinner. Please make sure if you are on **angular 7** then you must install **7.* version** of this library. Similarly if on **angular 8** then, use **8.* version** of ngx-spinner.

Issue on github for further help - https://github.com/Napster2210/ngx-spinner/issues/100

Comment: Still valid in 2023! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**First**: When you got this error, first you need to remove the imports of `Ngx` from `app.component.ts` and from all other components aswell.

**Second**: Remove your `Node Module` folder and use the command `npm install`.

In my case, I'm using angular 11 .